# Convertir .py a .exe (GUI)

Tags: python, pyqt5, exe, spyder

Como puedo generar un ejecutable de un archivo ".py" que depende de mas archivos ".py" (Son ventanas).
Ya lo he intentado con pyinstaller y con py2exe pero no me ejecuta mi programa, y tambien intente con auto-py-to-exe y este si ejecuta pero termina pesando alrededor de 700mb (Siendo que en si todos los .py que se usan pesan menos de 1 mb).

Comment: Cabe mencionar que hago uso de las librerias de PyQt5

Comment: estamos en las mismas, me sale un fatal error Failed to execute script, sera por que estoy usando librerias .ui
alguien nos ayuda????